# Doctrine 2 listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Hi I using Doctrine 2 listener to check if user group was change.
So I have
`- {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }` i my `service.yml`
The method is executed and Im doing such thing

```
$user = $args->getEntity();
$em   = $args->getEntityManager();

if($user instanceof \iTracker\UserBundle\Entity\User) {

    $u = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:User')->find($user->getId());
    var_dump($u->getUserGroup());
    var_dump($user->getUserGroup());
}
```

And both object are this same. Should object `$u` with old user group and $user with new group ?? Event is preUpdate so before update object should be different.

Comment: Could you write once again last part of your question or, alternatively, explain it better? I can't understand what is being asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the Doctrine documentation to see what you can get in the `preUpdate` lifecycle callback: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate

You have direct access to the original and changed values, so you don't have to query the database.

And to answer your question, why the two values are the same: I'm not 100% sure on that but most probably the `EntityManager` actually understands that you want to retrieve the same object as you already have, so it returns it without querying the database. To actually query the DB again you would have to somehow refresh the object in the EM (which will probably end up in loosing your changes).